# Take first argument from alias command and interpolate it to file name extension

Tags: bash, shell, aliases, positional-parameter

How to make alias that take argument and interpolate it to file extension to create it? I tired this and this doesn't work :

```
alias create-bash-file=' echo  "#!/bin/bash" > "$1.sh" '
```

as $1 is first argument and .sh is file extension and I wanted to make an alias that create a bash file included "#!/bin/bash" but the file name I want to take it as an argument so for example and I will write create-bash-file filename this should generate bash file called filename.sh

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aliases don't take arguments; functions do.

```
create-bash-file () {
    echo "#!/bin/bash" > "$1.sh"
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works but when I try to interpolate the argument to an url for example a git repo it's does work... functionName() { "git@github.com:user/$1.git"}

Comment: @KhaledDeveloper In that example, you need the `echo` command, and a semicolon or line break before the `}`.